# JBoss Custom lib directory

Tags: jboss, jakarta-ee, shared-libraries

I have this third party framework which comes with a huge set of dependent libraries, which by the way, have not yet been indexed in any Maven repository. I want to use this framework with some Web Apps, but for obvious reasons I don't want to put all those libraries under WEB-INF/lib, neither do I want just to place them all under `server/default/lib` to avoid mixing them with other local and third party libraries.

Is there some way under **JBoss 4.2.2** or higher to specify a custom lib directory for certain Web Apps? It's possible and/or advisable to have something like `server/default/lib/myAppLib`?

Any suggestion on this regard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, you have three options:

1. Package you WARs in an EAR and move the library JARs out of WEB-INF/lib and
   place them in a `lib` folder at the root of the EAR. No extra configuration required. This (non portable) solution is described in [Configuring JBoss shared libs](http://www.mastertheboss.com/en/jboss-server/211-configuring-jboss-shared-libs.html).
2. Move the library JARs out of WEB-INF/lib and place them into `server/xxx/lib`.
3. Deploy the JARs in the `deploy/` folder and disable WAR file class loader isolation.

I don't recommend option #3. Option #2 is what you don't want. This leaves us with option #1 (which is IMO the cleanest).

#### Related questions

- [Jboss shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108975/jboss-shared-library)
- [In JBoss can I configure a “shared library” location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842635/in-jboss-can-i-configure-a-shared-library-location)

Comment: Link has moved, currently it is http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-application-server/211-configuring-jboss-shared-libs.html

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following entry in your *server/default/conf/jboss-service.xml* for putting your jars in *server/default/myLibDir*:

```
<classpath codebase="myLibDir" archives="*"/>
```