# How to share libs between web applications with JBoss

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, classpath

I have 10 web applications deployed on JBoss. Each one has about 20 jars in web-inf/lib ... most of which are the same in each web application.

It's tedious to add all of these identical libraries to each WAR file. I'd rather just have these libraries shared across all applications. So I'd like to put all of these jar files in one place where all of the web applications can reference them.

Also, I only want 5 of these 10 web applications to reference these shared jar files, I want to pick and choose which applications references these shared libraries.

How could this be accomplished?

Comment: Duplicate of [Where to put a shared library in JBoss AS 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2108975/127035)?

Comment: Hmm... not sure that answers the last part of my question though. Can i pick and choose which apps use libs in that directory?

Comment: I think my question might actually duplicate this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305661/jboss-custom-lib-directory, though, the answers there don't seem great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use Maven to manage your dependencies.

Comment: You know what, I was literally just thinking that and was actually going to edit this post with that question. I could probably just have a common set of jar file in like a parent POM file or something that all of these different projects could inherit from.

Comment: Yes, either declare them in a parent POM or group them in a "dependency" POM as described here: http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html

Comment: Accepting this answer. I was ultimately looking for a way to avoid manually copying those jar files into each WAR and managing them individually ... by using a dependency management tool like Maven I am able to centrally manage the common dependency across all the applications.

Answer (score 0):

put the jars in [JBOSS SERVER]/lib directory, so the libraries are available for all application under this server. or this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108975/where-to-put-a-shared-library-in-jboss-as-5) might solve your issue.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if that's the complete answer ;-)  He wrote **only 5 of 10 apps** should reference it, if he follows this, **all** apps will ... or at least could ...

Answer (score 0):

You may drop the common jars into a location and provide the path during runtime

```
-Djboss.server.lib.url=file://shared/lib/path
```

For All application where you want jars in webapp/lib to override one in file://shared/lib/path Configure `jboss-web.xml`

**Scoped Class Isolation**

```
<jboss-web>
   <class-loading> 
      <loader-repository>com.example:archive=unique-archive-name</loader-repository> 
   </class-loading>
</jboss-web>
```

**Isolation with Overriding Server Classes**

```
<jboss-web>
   <class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">
      <loader-repository>
         com.example:archive=unique-archive-name
         <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
      </loader-repository>
   </class-loading>
 ...
```

See http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ClassLoadingConfiguration for further details